# OLEDB Source SSIS from SQL Server retrieving more rows than it should

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, oledb

I have an OLEDB Source connection from SQL server to retrieve data and send it to an Excel file.

[image]

The query contains an openquery that selects from an oracle linked server, when running the query on SSMS it retrieves 2050 rows, all good so far.

[image]

But when I run the package containing it, it keeps retrieving rows until the process hangs, (and retrieves more than 600k rows before that).

[image]

what could be the issue here? the user connected is the same as in the SSMS

Comment: Presumably the statements aren't the same, or you aren't connecting to the same host; and the other host (that you are connecting to via SSIS) has *a lot* more data.

Comment: You should connect to the oracle database youre retrieving data from and run your query there (or better yet do a count verions of said query). Like Larnu said, the source probably has WAY more data.

Comment: the statement is the same, (I'm copy/pasting it)  I was trying to use oracle source but it gives me an error (I have another question trying to solve this issue) so I went with OLEDB as workaround. it is the same host, I understand the possible issues you mention, but I'm sure I'm using the same information and query

Comment: @Larnu Also, the preview in the OLEDB Source does give me proper data, when it actually runs is when this error appears

Comment: Baldie47 , we don't have enough information to debug this. The preview could mean nothing if the source is defined by an expression, where the value changes when the package is run for example. The fact is that *something* is different, causing the data retrieved to be different. Unfortunately the only person with access to that information is you, not us. We can't open your package, connect to your instance, and look at the information. Like @DougCoats stated though, I would suggest connecting directly to the Oracle Instance from SSIS, not going to SQL Server first and then using `OPENQUERY`.